# CommunicationsException in webservice on Idle AWS instance

Tags: java, mysql, spring, web-services

I have two webservices. One webservice calls another webservice. These web services are hosted on two different instances of AWS. If webservice which is called is idle for some time, I am getting this exception -

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last
>   packet successfully  received from the server was 49,381,933
>   milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully  to the server
>   was 49,381,933 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured
>   value of  'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or
>   testing connection validity before  use in your application,
>   increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using
>   the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this
>   problem.

If I restart the AWS instance, I don't get this exception.

Tomcat is the server used, and Mysql as an database, webservices developed using spring-mvc.

I searched on internet, but found 'autoReconnect=true' is not recommended.
and not sure how much I can increase 'wait_timeout', as I am not sure how much time instance will be idle.

Please suggest what can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, there was a problem with connecting database with IP address, instead of that I used domain name of the server in the database connection string and problem got resolved.